# Attaching AngularJS 1.2.x routes to different/named views

Tags: angularjs

I'm rewriting a web app front-end using AngularJS. I'm still new to it, especially version 1.2.x.

I have an application with a static left-hand navigation that on link click, opens a second sidebar with various results (from an api/json response). For example, imagine clicking on a link "Categories" and then a new sidebar opens with a paginated list of category links.

There are multiple views possible for the secondary sidebar, so going to `#/categories` or `#/tags` show different content in it, as intended.

I'm trying to figure how to handle routing for the links inside the second sidebar, in such a way that it won't overwrite the view.

For example:

`#/categories` opens the sidebar, which has links to `#/categories/:cat`

Clicking on `#/categories/:cat` needs to have a route/controller so I can run some logic, but should not wipe the template shown by `#/categories`

I can't find much documentation on how this could work with Angular 1.2+

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/categories/:cat', {
            template : '',
            controller  : 'CategoryController',
            view: 'thisDoesntWork'
          })
    }]
)
```

Comment: So you need nested views?

Comment: Not nested, I just need a way to handle certain links that doesn't wipe the main view.

Comment: Can you confirm, you have 3 'areas' on your page: (1) Left hand navigation sidebar. (2) Second sidebar showing content depending on what is chosen on the first sidebar. (3) Content area showing content based on what was chosen on the second sidebar. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't an elegant build-in way to achieve what you want to do as currently `ngRoute` only supports a single `ngView` element in your html. You have some options:

1. Use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead of `ngRoute`. `ui-router` supports parallel and nested views.
2. Use `ngRoute` in combination with `ngInclude`. In your case your main html page will include the first static sidebar. The second sidebar will be loaded inside `ngInclude`, so your first sidebar will set a new template for `ngInclude` whenever you click on a navigation element. And then use `ngView` to show the main content based on whatever action you choose inside the second sidebar. So only the navigation items inside the second sidebar will change the browser location, i.e. angular route.

Comment: So far `ui-router` seems great. I'm realizing however that the only way to maintain both "views" on a page is to have a nested url. For example: `/:slug` loads `content` in the content view. `/recent` loads the "sidebar" list of recent entries. When you click a link in that sidebar, it can't go to `/:slug`, because that URL means the sidebar has no content. The only solution is to add a `/recent/:slug` option, and share the controller/template.

Comment: Ok, well I have it working. It's less efficient than I wanted but it's more of a resource/URL issue than an angular/js issue. I have to define routes like `/recent/:slug` and `/mine/:slug`, and then define two views for each - the sidebar, and the view/controller to handle the content.

Comment: In addition, every time the URL updates from clicking on the left sidebar, both views update/refresh. I'll need to find some way around these issues.

Comment: @helion3 post a simple plunker/fiddle with what you are doing. Pretty sure you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I've been able to get it mostly working... I needed to use the nested states that the example ur-router app uses. i.e. I needed a `categories` and a `categories.post` style nav. This solves the URL issue completely, however, it requires nested `ui-view`s in each template, but the content has to load outside the sidebar. I'll keep playing. As long as I can get the the child state stuff working, but not use nested views, I'll be ok

Comment: Well that was fast, I think I solved the view issue. Using the ampersand after the view name targets views outside the current parent view, i.e. `viewName@: {  }`. So far, it seems like it's working the way I want